# Python data extraction from online database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to download a CSV file from CELLTALKDB. I correctly enter the names of columns but in the downloaded CSV, the information was missing?

my code col_names are:

```py
col_names = ['lr_pair','ligand_gene_symbol','receptor_gene_symbol','ligand_gene_id', 'receptor_gene_id','ligand_ensembl_protein_id','receptor_ensembl_protein']
```

I have attached the download file and the original file please do comment if anyone has an idea.

[image: downloaded fileimage]

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make changes to your question to add more information. That is better than adding the information into a comment

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.read_csv("file.txt", delimiter='\t')
```

please note that your file is a text one

Comment: pathwaydata = []
    with contextlib.closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url=url)) as rd: # open url
        for df in pd.read_csv(rd,chunksize=1000,delimiter="\t"): I add your comment here but still the same file downloaded. let mw know if I add in a wrong place.